# NetCore 3.0.0 Framework version not found, even though it is installed in MacOS

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to port some legacy code in net framework to net core. I have already done that successfully  in Windows 10 (it fully compiles and runs). I am now trying to make it run in MacOS Mojave, since I have a mac and would rather not have to work with a virtual machine.

The code compiles properly, but when it tries to run it the system says that it can't find the proper version of net core.

I have already tried to reinstall Visual Studio having previously installed netcore.

I have also tried to do the "hello world" example and it compiles and runs flawlessly.

The error it shows is:

```sh
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.0.0-preview5-27626-15' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The .NET Core frameworks can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

dotnet --info gives:

```sh
~ dotnet --info
SDK de .NET Core (reflejando cualquier global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100-preview5-011568
 Commit:    b487ff10aa

Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview5-011568/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15
  Commit:  61f30f5a23

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.505 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.0.100-preview5-011568 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview5-19227-01 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I don't know where could be the problem; I expect the program to run, as the proper runtime is installed.

Comment: Looking at your error message, the `dotnet` cli is looking for a framework called `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` to be installed, this is only supported on Windows machines

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doesn't this post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/ suggest that there would be support for windows desktop apps in netcore 3.0?

Comment: Windows Forms and WPF are available in .NET Core 3.0 when the app is running on Windows. To quote the article: "Support for Windows desktop will be added as a set of “Windows Desktop Packs”, which will only work on Windows"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use Windows Forms/WPF frameworks, which are not supported on MacOS.

Comment: Thanks. Looking a bit more in detail in other posts and such it looks like that is indeed the case, and there seems to be no plans for net core to support windows forms in linux and macOS. I misunderstood the implications of having windows forms available in net core 3.